# SQL CASE SUBQUERY COUNT

Tags: sql, count, case

I have table with 2 col :

```
UID    NAME
-----------
111    AAA
222    BBB
```

Customer will enter the name and I have to retrieve UID with respective value. If name won't present in the rows, it has to retrieve 000, not like no rows.

I am trying to write query like this:

```
SELECT  
   CASE UID 
      WHEN Count(*) = 0 THEN '000'
      ELSE UID 
   END
FROM table1   
WHERE NAME ='XXX'
```

Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

If UID is an integer, then you need to take casts into account:

```
select coalesce(cast(max(uid) as char(3)), '000')
from table1
where name = 'XXX'
```

The cast is intended to be to the type of UID, which seems to be char(3) in your example.

When there are no matching rows, then the `max()` function returns NULL.  The `coalesce()` turns this into the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select case
           when max(id) is null then
            0
           else
            max(id)
       end
  from table1
 where name = 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in case

```
SELECT case when count(UID) = 0 THEN '000' ELSE UID end FROM table1 where name = 'XXX'
```

sqlfiddle :http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/257ea/1